# How to use the click jquery function with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When a user clicks on the textbox, the font in the textbox should change color, but for some reason it does not.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".textbox0").click(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(64, 0, 128)');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .textbox0 {
      position: fixed;
      left: 131px;
      top: 38px;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 8px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="textbox0"><textarea rows=7 cols=30>Change colour</textarea></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe I did everything correctly as this method worked with buttons, but I guess I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the change to the `textarea` element, not the `div`:

```
$(".textbox0 textarea").click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'rgb(64, 0, 128)');
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XGPt9/12/).

If you need to keep the `click` event handler bound to the `.textbox0` element and not the `textarea`, you could use the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (or [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)) method within the event handler to apply the change to the `textarea`:

```
$(".textbox0").click(function() {
    $(this).find("textarea").css("color", "rgb(64, 0, 128)");
});
```

Comment: It'd be great if you would explain *why* this is, but I have a hunch you aren't so sure yourself.

Comment: I do know why this is (and there is little point in my explaining it now since you have done so in your answer). Why do you have a hunch that I would not know that? Also, as the OP would like to change the colour of the `textarea`, what happens with your method if there is more text in the `div` at some point? Applying the change to the `div` would cause an unwanted change to that text, although it would affect the `textarea` too.

Comment: You're making the assumption A) the `div` serves a purpose other than manipulating the position of the `textarea`, B) additional text will be added to it in the future, and C) the application of the color to the `textarea` is unintentional. Teach a man to fish…

Comment: And you're making the opposite assumptions! Both of our methods have their advantages, and both have their disadvantages. Both are valid answers.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions. Read the first sentence in the question where the expectation and problem are spelled out plainly. I pointed out the problem. There's not anything inherently wrong with making assumptions to better guide, I just think it makes more sense to actually guide than just share the "corrected" version and sending the asker along none the wiser about the problem.

Comment: I agree that you have pointed out the reason why the OPs code does not work. However the first line of the question reads "When a user clicks on the textbox..." so why bind to the `div` and inherit the `color` property from it when the `textarea` is what should be affected? As I said, we are both right and should probably leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

**This is NOT because your** `click` **binding needs to be on the textarea.**

Nor is it because you need to use a named CSS color.

Nor is it related to the onDomReady event.

All you need to make your code work is a simple line of CSS:

```
textarea { color: inherit; }
```

The reason the text in your textarea isn't changing color is that the user-styles for most browsers are of higher cascade precedence than `inherit`. This is good, otherwise you would see some very bizarre looking textareas floating around. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the "textarea" tag in your accessor.

I put the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/qfvVv/

Answer (score 0):

The change in the stylesheet is being done on the `div`, not on the `textarea` inside the div.

You can change this in several ways:
Put the class on the `textarea`
or change your jQuery selector to `.textbox0 textarea`
or change the code in the click event to change the css of the textarea in the div.